# Error when running Ruby gem but local directory works fine

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I built a gem called "Knitpickr" and published it to RubyGems.org. The program runs fine when I run it in its local directory; however, when I install the gem and run it, I receive the following error message:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/knitpickr-0.1.8/lib/knitpickr/controller.rb
:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Knitpickr (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/knitpickr0.1.8/lib/knitpickr.
rb:4:in `require_relative'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/knitpickr-0.1.8/lib/knitpickr.
rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/knitpickr-0.1.8/bin/knitpickr:
3:in `require_relative'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/knitpickr-0.1.8/bin/knitpickr:
3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/knitpickr:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/knitpickr:23:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `ev
al'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<m
ain>'
```

I think it isn't recognizing the Knitpickr module namespacing for some reason. Here is the code that the error is referring to:

```
class Knitpickr::Controller
```

I have the gemspec file set (or, at least, as far as I understand) to run from the lib/knitpickr.rb file, which includes the following:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

require_relative './knitpickr/controller'
require_relative './knitpickr/scraper'
require_relative './knitpickr/version'
require_relative './knitpickr/yarn'

module Knitpickr
end
```

The module is defined there, so I'm confused on why "Knitpickr" is being seen as an uninitialized constant in the controller.rb file.

**What is confusing me the MOST is why the program runs fine in its local directory but hits an error when running the gem.**

The gem can be installed with

```
gem install knitpickr
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the trace, `knitpickr` failed before it even intialized Knitpickr module. You are requiring controller before initializing your module.

Move your module initialization above require relatives.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

module Knitpickr
end

require_relative './knitpickr/controller'
require_relative './knitpickr/scraper'
require_relative './knitpickr/version'
require_relative './knitpickr/yarn'
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was - thanks so much! The gem works now.